# Are there coding standards for the position of Include and Require?

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I've been recently more mindful of coding standards and trying to make sure I follow best practices. Working with Laravel blade, I've always been putting statements such as `require(file)` and `include(file)` at the top of my code. Putting it on the top was primarily just how I've been exposed to how I should add them, since most of the files included or required are handled throughout the code I'm using them in.

However, I recently got into a situation where I only needed to include a file when a certain condition was met. As such, I had the file coded as

```
if(condition){
    include(file)
    ...
}
```

I was wondering if this would still follow suit with general coding standards, or if this goes against acceptable practice?

Comment: The short answer is *no* and this question will probably be closed as primarily opinion based... my tuppence worth, use `require` when it's a required file, e.g. `require '/www/servers/site/cfg/live.php';` since it's required for stuff to work it's going to be at the top by default. I would generally only use `include` for template/view files and then then it appears in the code where necessary; in a routing script, as a rough example: `if($found_path) { include $found_path; } else { ... 404 ... }` sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Before PHP had namespaces, then putting include/require at the top of a script, unconditionally, meant that you would see any namespace collisions early in testing. The downside of doing this was that there would be a performance overhead dealing with code which might not be required.

I have seen code written to use different include files based on some condition arising. While this is the only practical way to implement a front controller architecture, anywhere *other* than in the front controller, I would say that this is a very bad idea. And even *in* the front controller, it is probably a better idea to use an autoloader.

Now that PHP has explicit support for namespaces, the argument for explicitly including all the code does not carry as much weight - but you still need to ensure that your namespaces down't collide unintentionally.

Having said that, a side-effect of explicitly putting all your include/require statements at the top of the file makes it simpler to manage dependencies and there are fewer calculated values in scope - hence there's less opportunity for programmers to use calculated paths and its a lot easier to carry out security audits of the code to find horrible things like:

```
include($_GET['function'] . "/index.php");
```